# Weird Vscode terminal/output

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Hey i was coding a C program with vscode today and out of nowhere when I runned my code through code runner the output looked like this
[image]

and when I switched it to the regular bash terminal it looks like this
[image]

It seems to run the program fine and for bash it runs terminal commands normally so this might only be the font of the terminal.. How can i fix this back?

this is my settings.json
[image]

Edit: Typing on the terminal made me realized that as I type, the text cursor comes glitched in the already printed text which might mean that it is not only the fault of the font?